# Как сделать выбраный пункт в Select активным

Tags: html, select

Я сделал выпадающий список меню элемента **select** и установил определенную категорию со значением **value="4"**

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="city_id">
  <option disabled="Figure"></option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
  <option value="4">Four</option>
</select>
<script>
  $("select#city_id").val("4");
</script>
```

Задача состоит в том ,чтобы сделать элемента **value="4"** постоянно активным ,тоесть при открытии страницы, автоматически выпадал список со значение "Four" и не возможно было выбрать другой элемента списка .
Вопрос возможно ли это сделать ?

Answer (score 4):

Можно всё это сделать без JS. Просто на сам селект говорите что он отключен и на нужный элемент говорите что он выбран, вот так:

```html
<select id="city_id" disabled>
  <option value="Figure"></option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
  <option value="4" selected>Four</option>
</select>
```

В этом случае правда не увидите другие элементы списка, если хотите чтоб список выпадал, но нельзя было выбрать тогда надо на все остальные элементы списка повесить атрибут disabled:

```html
<select id="city_id">
  <option value="1" disabled>One</option>
  <option value="2" disabled>Two</option>
  <option value="3" disabled>Three</option>
  <option value="4" selected>Four</option>
</select>
```

Есть ещё вариант указать атрибут size, тогда список будет как бы открыт и его нельзя будет закрыть:

```html
<select id="city_id" size="4">
  <option value="1" disabled>One</option>
  <option value="2" disabled>Two</option>
  <option value="3" disabled>Three</option>
  <option value="4" selected>Four</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Задача другая ,ваш пример я уже про бывал, надо что бы список автоматически выпал ,тоже самое если бы я нажал на него и нельзя было его закрыть.Это возможно ?

Comment: Ну не совсем это, но есть вариант, ответ обновил

Comment: Возможно сделать окно списка активным,чтобы оно выделялось,эмитировать нажатие на это окно ?

Comment: Можно, но при клике куда либо оно скроется, а так через jquery просто используете триггер - $("select#city_id").trigger('click');

Comment: К сожалению клик происходит ,но окно не выделяется.

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо решение нашел.

$('option[value="4"]').attr('selected', 'selected').parent().focus();